# Sharing an MP4 file between MediaCodec and MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediacodec

Trying to read from the same MP4 file with a `MediaCodec` (decoder) instance **and** a `MediaPlayer` instance doesn't work as expected. When pausing (or seeking) and then resuming playback, the `MediaPlayer`'s position is unpredictable and will often jump ahead of the `MediaCodec` decoder by 100-500 ms.

In my application, the decoder is handling H.264 video frames and the `MediaPlayer` is playing AAC audio. Both have been initialized with the same on-device MP4 file.

Some observations:

- Playback from the beginning of the file (without pausing or seeking) works fine
- The audio nearly always jumps ahead of the video after seeking or pausing
- Profiling showed that the "jump" appears to happen just after resuming playback; prior to resuming, both components report the same playback position. Just after resuming, there is a large and sudden change in the `MediaPlayer`'s position.
- The audio remains ahead of the video by a constant amount after the jump

Letting each component use its own identical copy of the MP4 works fine, and that's how I solved the problem for now. I am aware that `MediaCodec` can be used to process audio, but I would prefer to avoid that approach.

After combing through the relevant AOSP code ([MediaCodec](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/MediaCodec.java), [MediaPlayer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java), and some JNI classes), it isn't clear to me how these components would be interfering with one another. Do they share a low-level Binder object? Is the `MediaPlayer` somehow (re)using the cursor that the `MediaCodec` decoder is using to fill its input buffers?

Comment: MediaPlayer use its own player engine that runs in a separate process and is somewhat asynchronous, so I'm not surprised that it's difficult to synchronize with your own player implementation in your own process. However that doesn't explain why making a copy of the file and then letting each player use its own copy of the file makes things work. Can you post some code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have time this week to scrub the code into a form that can be shared.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It's proving difficult to isolate the relevant code into a form that's safe to share. May I contact you privately? My email is in my profile.

Comment: If this helps, when I use `MediaPlayer.seekTo()` while a `MediaExtractor` with the same data source is running, the `MediaPlayer` would freeze for a while and the `MediaExtractor` would return no extracted data.